# How to create array of objects from nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am getting the following array of objects, how can I create/split these into multiple array of objects. We have to check if the inner array of serialNumbers is not empty then we have to create a new object that will contains the old data of outer array object plus the first value of the inner array object and so on...

```
0: {id: 288, name: "22", price: 3, Inventories: Array(1), SerialNumbers: Array(2)}
1: {id: 289, name: "3", Price: 3, Inventories: Array(1), SerialNumbers: Array(0)}
2: {id: 290, name: "4", Price: 3, Inventories: Array(1), SerialNumbers: Array(0)}
```

I want to achieve something like this

```
0: {id: 288, name: "22", price: 3, Inventories: Array(1), SerialNumbers:1 }
1: {id: 288, name: "22", price: 3, Inventories: Array(1), SerialNumbers:2 }
2: {id: 289, name: "3", Price: 3, Inventories: Array(1), SerialNumbers: null}
3: {id: 290, name: "4", Price: 3, Inventories: Array(1), SerialNumbers: null}
```

I tried this but I am not able to achieve the results.

```
this.data = response.map((obj) => {
        return {...obj, ... obj.VariantSerialNumbers}
      });
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense enough for people to understand. Please rephrase your question and perhaps include some more code.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: please share in the learning/solving process by showing that you've tried to do this. That way we know we're not just being asked to write someone's code like an employee.

Comment: Elaborate what you are trying to achieve and what is the usage of this json data ?

Comment: a simple spread operation would do the trick

Comment: @Kinglish I'd be curious to see a spread operation example...

Comment: @perpetual-light - actually it wasn't as straight forward as i thought and after a while, I felt yours was clearer and easier to read.

Comment: Coulda been cool though... I don't find myself using it too often for that reason though. It didn't really live up to the hype of flexibility from the initial release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
this.data = response.map((value, index) => {
  if (!!value.SerialNumbers.length)
    return value.SerialNumbers.map((number) => {
      let obj = Object.assign({}, value);
      obj.SerialNumbers = number;
      return obj;
    })
  value.SerialNumbers = null;
  return value;
}).flatten()
```

First map into the root array then map through the SerialNumbers if present. Then you flatten the result to "undo" the nested array result.

Comment: With some little tweaks I am able to get the desired results. Thank you :)